# Tabular line problem when inserting symbol

Tags: tables, symbols

When I insert `\Omega` in tabular the vertical line in that row gets out of allignment.

Code snippet:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1cm}|p{4cm}|p{3cm}|p{1.5cm}|  }
\hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Parts list} \\
 \hline
 ITEM NO. & PART NAME & SPECIFICATION & QTY.\\
 \hline
 14 & Indikatorlampe & Patlite RGB & 1\\
 \hline
 14 & Potmeter & Linear 10k\Omega & 1\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Result: [image: Screenshot of the problem]

Can someone please help me? :)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please include fully compileable minimum working examples, rather than just code snippets.  The missing code not only has to be retyped by those who would otherwise try to help you, but it may also contain key information that would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: You should use [package `siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to print units like kilo ohm.

Comment: And the `tabular` rows should end with `\\ ` not with `\\\ `.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing a few outright typos in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `\Omega` should be processed in math mode. Hence, don't write

```
Linear 10k\Omega
```

Instead, you should write

```
Linear 10k$\Omega$
```

Better still, as already suggested by @Schweinebacke, load the [siunitx](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx?lang=en) package and write

```
Linear \SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}
```

Doing so will give you an appropriate amount of whitespace between the number and the unit.

Comment: Thank you both very much! This is greatly appreciated :)